# assembly conflict Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms

Tags: asp.net

After running a update to published app i get a error :

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/XXX/Pages/MainMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"  
Line 2:  CodeBehind="Report.aspx.cs" Inherits="xxx.yy.cc.tt.Pages.Reports.Report" %><%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
```

I haven't updated that to 10.0 -> it should be 9.0 . It is 9 in web.config.. Also it is 9.0 for other apps running in same server. So I  wonder, where can it get that request command to search for 10.0 version?

As I use Visual Studio 2012 for development, I think it mistakenly did it automatically in some phase. However, as I'm beginner I dont know where to search for that "automatically" modified configuration.

Copy-Paste of Web.config:

```
<compilation debug="false" defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        </assemblies>
        <buildProviders>
            <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </buildProviders>
    </compilation>

    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
```

Also its weird if i run the same version i updated it with in my local machine it works.

Comment: There might be a couple places specified in your web.config.  Check in the compilation section in both the buildprovider section and assembly section.

Comment: I use build script for update. I dont copy web.config to server. And it started to give this error after update. So I'm pretty sure it has to be somewhere else. But checking.. -> nope i refer only onto 9.0 version .. :S

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253607/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-reportviewer-common-version-11-0-0-0/33670464#33670464)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran into a similar problem
Solution:
- Open the References tab on the project that references 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms'
- Select the reference - Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, right click and select the properties option from the context menu.
- On the Properties tab ensure that Copy to local is set to True.

Answer (score 2):

I have Just deleted the lines of assemblies from the web.config file and it worked fine for me....
:)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: ohh sure... let me learn more before posting such inappropriate answers... thanks @SimonMartin :)

Comment: pega wega you are right! it works!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the refences form the project, delete all the nodes with `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms` and `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common` from the `web.config` and now add the references again.

Compile and it should be all good

Comment: Basicly as it worked for me on local i just updated it again - worked.. No idea what casued that error :S
but thanks :)

Comment: basically you were referencing some old dll. This procedure will reset that and re-add the entries in your web.config. And please, check the big mark if you think that this is the answer at your question.

Comment: Problem with this answer is that I have hundreds of pages that use the WebForms dll (using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;), so I cannot re-compile the project like you say after removing the reference from the project

Answer (score 1):

In production server:
1st. Install reportviewer.exe version 10.
2nd. Stop and start the pool in iis used for your application.

These steps worked for me in ws2003 and asp.net 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration file under these various sections:

```
<compilation ...>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
 </assemblies>

  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
.
.
<httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
        validate="false" />
 </httpHandlers>
```

These may refer to 10, but should be 9.

Comment: nop, all are refering to 9 - updated my question with copy-paste from web-config