# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I recently upgraded my n-tier solution from **.NET 3.5 vs 2008 to 4.5 visual studio 2012**. Every thing went fine apart from crystal reports and I had to install new runtime crystal reports for visual studio 2012 from the following link http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_5.exe.
After installing the above package I had to resolve some deprecated function and properties of 
CrystalViewer and after that reports rendering properly in development environment **(Windows 7 64 bit, SQL Server 2005, Visual Studio 2012)**. When I deployed the package in test environment windows server 2008 R2
the Application failed to load by throwing error 
Could not load file or assembly **Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11**

I managed to resolve ReportViewer.WebForms error by copying the DLL 
from **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\ReportViewer** to bin folder of solution and set property **copylocal = true** and deployed the package. After that I received the error **Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0** . I tried to search that DLL on my machine but couldn't. when project is running in visual studio, In **Debug-> Windows->Module**  the file is not listed however in global assembly cache that file is installed but I don't know how its installed to global cache and from where .  I found one solution that I had to install **ReportViewer.msi** from microsoft package but if i install this package it asks me to install SQL Server 2012 which I dont wan't. Could any one help me to resolve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can install the Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime and change your references so they point to the ones installed by the runtime.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35747

I have installed the runtime without it asking for SQL Server 2012. Before installing try uninstalling any previous versions of report viewer.

Comment: thanks. when i try to install reportviewer.msi on windows server 2008 it says the "the file was blocked as it did not have a valid digital signature that verifies its publisher. when i click unknown publisher, check certificate, install certificate. It still does not work. any idea how to get rid from this issue

Comment: Managed to install the reportviewer on windows server 2008. the dll error is gone but the report page is still blank in crystal viewer.

Comment: If you don't want to install this on the server, there's also a NuGet package by the same name that you can add to your web project.

Comment: I have a web app installed in a server and when I try to access the web application I get the same error. Does the server need to have the ReportViewer.msi installed? I can debug it in my computer and it works fine.

Comment: You may also have to install "Microsoft® System CLR Types" before you can install the package, that is located [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29065).

Answer (score 60):

Dont know if this is good to anyone, but search all these dlls:

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll

You find them in `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\...`, and then put them in the references of your project.

For each of them say: local copy, and check for 32 or 64 bit solution.

Comment: Great Answer. This worked for me only adding the `MicrosoftReportViewer.Common` and `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms` with Copy Local set to *true*. I imagine the requirement of the others listed in the answer are dependent upon the type of report in use.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day, for my WinForms 2013 c# app changing to "Local Copy" for `MicrosoftReportViewer.Common.dll` and `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll` did the job!

Comment: Thank you very much! I was pulling a package down from our live server and couldn't find the reference in visual studio for this. Browsing to that file location, found them right away.

Comment: I ran this to get a file copy of the GAC: @echo off
cd  c:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL 
xcopy . C:\users\_yourdirectory_\temp\GacDump /s /y

Comment: you guys are awesome

Answer (score 27):

As *Microsoft.ReportViewer.2012.Runtime* has `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms`, `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common` and `Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel` libraries, just run this command on PM Console:

> Install-Package Microsoft.ReportViewer.2012.Runtime

**Note :** If you want to completely remove the old `Microsoft.ReportViewer.xxx` references, you can remove them from *Manage NuGet Packages>Installed Packages* menu and then remove the related lines from `packages.config` file in your project. After that it will not comeback again during building of the project.

Answer (score 10):

**Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Webforms'**
or

**Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common'**

This issue occured for me in Visual studio 2015.

**Reason:**

the reference for Microsoft.ReportViewer.Webforms dll is missing.

**Possible Fix**

**Step1:**

To add "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Webforms.dll" to the solution.

Navigate to Nuget Package Manager Console as

"Tools-->NugetPackageManager-->Package Manager Console".

Then enter the following command in console as below

PM>Install-Package Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.WebForms

Then it will install the Reportviewer.webforms dll in "..\packages\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.WebForms.12.0.2402.15\lib" (Your project folder path)

and ReportViewer.Runtime.Common dll in "..\packages\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.Common.12.0.2402.15\lib". (Your project folder path)

**Step2:-**

Remove the existing reference of "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms". 
we need to refer these dll files in our Solution as "Right click Solution >References-->Add reference-->browse ".
Add both the dll files from the above paths.

**Step3:**

Change the web.Config File to point out to Visual Studio 2015.
comment out both the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms and Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common  version 11.0.0.0 and Uncomment both the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms and Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common Version=12.0.0.0. as attached in screenshot.

[Microsoft.ReportViewer.Webforms/Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXk8h.png)

Also refer the link below.

[Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493817/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-reportviewer-webforms)

Comment: Step 1 did it for me!

Answer (score 8):

You can download the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportViewer.2015.Runtime/) too.

Comment: Does that NuGet package include WebForms?

Comment: By looking at the package - No.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem for Winforms.

The solution for me is:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.Winforms
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply install Microsot.ReportViewer.2012.Runtime nuget package as shown in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33014040/2198830

Comment: Best solution for me. Plus, with nuget it come with all dependencies. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add Microsot.ReportViewer 2010 or 2012 in prerequisite of setup project then it first install Report Viewer if it's not present in "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL..." and after installing, it installs set up project

Answer (score 2):

I Had the same problem.

The solution for me is:

You must have the same version of: Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel registred in C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel,
like you have registraded in web.config in developer server:

[image]

In my case i was only registred the 13. version in my prodution server and i have the 12. version in developer server.

the solution is install the version 12. in the prodution server too

the version 12. :

https://download.microsoft.com/download/A/1/2/A129F694-233C-4C7C-860F-F73139CF2E01/ENU/x86/ReportViewer.msi

Then now i have the version 12. in the prodution and the report work fine.

*** Remember to reset your IIS after instalation

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll' assembly is not required for my project, so I simply removed all references (Project -> Add Reference... -> ...)  (all requirements from Publish tab the VS2013 removed automatically) and all works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem, searching the dll's file in C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\ and copied to bin directory of the proyect deployed. That work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Although rather late, but you can manually download the required DLLs from nuget at the following link:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.Common/12.0.2402.15

Open the file .Rar Archive, extract the dlls and copy them manually to the bin folder of your publish.

This solution worked for me. Hope that helps !!

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by download the reportviewer.exe and install it.
After the installation, all related assemblies will be available in C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL, then you can refer it in web config