# Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common Version=12.0.0.0

Tags: .net, reportviewer

I'm getting the following exception in my Windows Service Application:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I cannot find a download url for version 12 and setting the files to "Include" and "Prequisite (Auto)" does not solve the problem in this Windows Service Application, although it works fine in my WinForms Application and results in the appropriate files being included and referenced along with all other requisite .DLLs.

Can someone either help me get this Windows Service Application to include the files, or lead me to a download link that will install Version 12 in the GAC?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio 2013 installed?

Comment: I'm actually using VS 2012 to develop on.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253607/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-reportviewer-common-version-11-0-0-0/33670464#33670464)?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Version 12 of the ReportViewer bits is referred to as *Microsoft Report Viewer 2015 Runtime* and can downloaded for installation from the following link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496

**UPDATE:**

The ReportViewer bits are also available as a NUGET package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.Common/12.0.2402.15

`Install-Package Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.Common`

Comment: I'm trying this now.  When trying to install the download I get an error about MS SQL CLR Types 2014 needing to be on the machine.  I'm getting that download now (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42295) and will mark this as the answer once I confirm all works.  Thank you!

Comment: Where are they installed?

Comment: The package Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.Common wasn't adding the file Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll to the output \bin for one of my sites so I had to add the Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.v12 package, in case anyone else runs into this weird corner case.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting this error after deploying on IIS Server PC.

1. First Install Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Feature Pack

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295[enter link description here](http://%20https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295)

2. Install Microsoft Report Viewer 2015 Runtime redistributable package

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496

It may require restart your computer.

Comment: For the "SQL Server 2014 Feature Pack" you only need to install Microsoft® System CLR Types for Microsoft SQL Server® 2014 (SQLSysClrTypes.msi).

Answer (score 5):

I worked on this issue for a few days. Installed all packages, modified web.config and still had the same problem. I finally removed

```
<assemblies>
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
</assemblies>
```

from the web.config and it worked. No exactly sure why it didn't work with the tags in the web.config file. My guess there is a conflict with the GAC and the BIN folder.

Here is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />     
    </httpHandlers>    
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />      
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Issue

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms / Winforms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

## Cause

Microsoft ReportViewer runtime and SQL CLR Types for SQL Server 2014 is required to run and is missing from the server hosting Internet Information Services (IIS) or your application.

## Resolution

Install the following packages on the IIS server and then restart the system:

Download [Microsoft ReportViewer runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496)

Download [Microsoft SQL CLR types for SQL Server 2014](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295)

Once restarted connect to Web service / Your app again and verify that the error has been resolved.

Or you cant follow this [link](https://support.pitneybowes.com/VFP06_KnowledgeWithSidebarTroubleshoot?id=kA280000000PFIYCA4&popup=false&lang=en_US) to read more.

Comment: Hello! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

In My cases, After installing Sql server data tools by Visual Studio 2015 installer, problem has been resolved

[Here is the screenshot for installing data tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSooO.png)

Answer (score 1):

First install SQLSysClrTypes for Ms SQL 2014 and secondly install ReportViewer for ms sql 2014

Restart your application or project, in my case its resolved.

Answer (score 0):

here the link to webreports version 12
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.v12/12.0.0?_src=template

after the package installed

on your toolbox browse the dll reference it to bin then that's it run the visual studio