# Add Reporting.WinForms Reference to VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, report

I'm looking at adding the reference;

> Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms

to my VisualStudio (2015) project but when I go to Add the Reference in the Solution Explorer I couldn't find it.

Eventually I added it through `NuGet` but now I am getting the error message;

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

which leads me to believe I just haven't added the package properly. I've installed *Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools* through program features but still no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253607/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-reportviewer-common-version-11-0-0-0)

Comment: @stuartd I've tried everything suggested in those questions but to no avail unfortunately.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253607/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-reportviewer-common-version-11-0-0-0/33670464#33670464)?

Answer (score 9):

You can try by executing this into Package Manager Console

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.v11
```