# Unable to render Report into PDF in Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, pdf, rdlc

I'm facing one of the most strangest technical problem in `.NET`. I've written following logic to export report to `PDF` which is working in all the `systems` except `Windows Server 2012`. What could be the problem? I tried using the latest `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winforms.dll`, but that too didn't help. Please help me if someone has any idea to deal with this.

```
reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamids;
            string mimeType, encoding, filenameExtension;
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(report.AssemblyName);
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(report.ReportName);
            reportViewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(stream);                
            //reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            //reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            //lr = reportViewer.LocalReport;
            //lr.ReportPath = "Reports\\CommentReport.rdlc";
            reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();                
            foreach (var dataSource in report.DataSources)
            {
                reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(dataSource.Key, dataSource.Value));
            }

            pdfByteArray = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);
```

Comment: try setting all related references property- Specific Version  to True.

Comment: I did that. But it didn't help.

Comment: What is the error you're getting? I believe this might very well solve your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22253867/4579864