# Could not load assmbly MicrosoftReportViewer Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting

I uploaded `.net` my project godaddy windows hosting then I got an error which is about custom error.

I configured webconfig custom error `mode=off` then I got that error.

I cant fix it. May you help me about that. What Can I do for fixing that problem?

[image: issue]

Comment: Refer to this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d5d438e2-48ee-4525-8e85-f2cc0ede879b/configuration-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftreportviewerwebforms?forum=tfswebaccess

Comment: One more: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f6f4659c-5837-4da1-81af-4cd857f0a206/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftreportviewerwebforms-version10000-cultureneutral?forum=sqlreportingservices and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253607/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-reportviewer-common-version-11-0-0-0

Comment: Ask the godaddy experts(customer care) to help in it.