# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=13.0.0.0

Tags: c#, wpf, reportviewer

When I try to view report like:

```
ReportViewer.ReportHost.LocalReport.SetParameters(pr);
```

I get this exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 
>   Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=13.0.0.0

I can't find the assembly `Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=13.0.0.0` anywhere. The file is not on my computer and I couldn't find it on the web either.

Where can I find this dll?

Comment: did you add this dll to your project references? does it have a yellow mark on its icon?

Comment: I already add Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common and Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms and both are version 13.0.0.0     but I can't find Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll any where.

Comment: The problem not solved yet, please help

Answer (score 1):

After executing `ReportViewer.exe` found in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\sdk\Bootstrapper\Packages\ReportViewer\ReportViewer.exe

the dll `Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel` should be created in `GAC` folder:

> %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\

Comment: This is really my problem I think, I didn't found ReportViewer.exe in the mentioned path, Instead I found only SqlClrTypes_x64 folder, and no dll for Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel found in GAC Folder, What I am missing :(

Comment: @MajdAlbaho could you do a search for ReportViewer.exe on your computer?

Comment: @MajdAlbaho you can first look inside the GAC folder. it might be already there

Comment: I downloaded report viewer from microsoft : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496 and install it.

Comment: please can you connect remotely on my PC on "AnyDesk" :)

Comment: @MajdAlbaho I'm afraid that's not possible and will not be useful for future readers. this post might have the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22253607/366064

Comment: then please, where can I found Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll version 13.0.0.0 to download it please help

Comment: @MajdAlbaho I don't know I haven't found v13 on the web. It may be included in another bundle. maybe you should ask Microsoft support team.